# Ошибка flutter сразу после установки

Tags: flutter

Только установил flutter и anroid studio, и тут сразу ошибка вылетела:

````
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_351' used by Gradle. Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1```
````

Comment: в терминале android studio выполните flutter doctor -v и прикрепите результат в описание проблемы